# Why does Firefox & Chrome run so slow on Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, lubuntu

I need to determine why my Gmail, etc. performs dog slow in Firefox 78 and Chrome 91 browsers on my Lubuntu 14.04 system.

It's a Dell Latitude laptop with an i5-4300U processor and 16 Gigs RAM, connected to hardwired high speed internet (the same system ran gmail at lightning fast speed on Windows 7).

I'm running nothing but LUBUNTU (not Ubuntu), which is especially easy on resources, but for some reason both browsers acts like it's on 2400 baud dialup.

Results of internet speed tests for Firefox are about the same between Lubuntu & Windows; in Lubuntu it says download speed is 70 Mbps in Firefox  (although for some reason, Chrome gives results about half that).

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

EDIT WITH ADDITIONAL INFO:

1. both browsers are operating with a clean fresh config (no extensions)
2. I'm running the liveUSB version of Lubuntu so the hard disk is not used, everything operating off RAM (16 GB)
3. output of `free` command

```
root@fi:~# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      16337164    1799624   14537540     516148     179848    1213604
-/+ buffers/cache:     406172   15930992
Swap:      8168576          0    8168576
```

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of disk you are using. Both browsers use a lot of disk even when RAM is plentiful. Also, was this the same disk as the Windows 7 setup?

Comment: Do you have the proper drivers installed for whatever graphics your system has?

Comment: Lubuntu 14.04? That's a 7 year old release, unsupported for over 2 years at this point.

Comment: @draca Lubuntu does not run off RAM by default. If you are using an Lubntu liveUSB, it is running off your flash drive. If you use a [distro that does use a RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions_that_run_from_RAM), you can test this yourself. One easy way to tell the difference is that you can remove the installation media, i.e. unplug the flash drive and keep using the OS.

Comment: @Nathaniel, in the past I have seen lightning fast performance running Lubuntu from liveUSB, not sure what changed now. Also USB 2.0 is very fast.  Right now, the issue seems to be either in the network performance (via cat5 ethernet) or something slowing down the browser's javascript engine. Correct me if I'm not looking at the right thing

Comment: @draca If it's just Gmail, I suppose it could be a network issue. A few questions: where are you getting the Lubuntu 14.04 image? [Ubuntu's website doesn't list it anymore](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/). Out of curiosity, I tried an [Ubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.5/) and didn't observe anything like you describe. Could you post the results of [Jetstream](https://browserbench.org/JetStream/)? Also, please, the output of `df -T ~` and `ioping -c 10 ~`. (You may need to install `ioping` It's in the `universe` repository.)

Comment: @Nathaniel, I've had this 14.04 image for years, from their official site, ever since it was the current version so it has a history of having a fast browser until recently.  
The Jetstream score for the browser is only 6.570, which I see is very slow compared to what I ran on a similar powered computer running Win7.
While Jetstream was running, a messagebar on the top repeatedly kept being displayed after I dismissed it, saying "This page is slowing down Firefox. To speed up your browser, stop this page"

Comment: @Nathaniel:
root@fi:/home/root# df -T ~
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlay   8168580 592284   7576296   8% /

Comment: root@fi:/home/sa/.vnc# ioping -c 10 ~
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=1 time=34 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=2 time=8 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=3 time=35 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=4 time=8 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=5 time=36 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=6 time=36 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=7 time=36 us
4.0 KiB from /home/lubuntu (overlay /cow): request=8 time=8 us
(out of space; last 2 were 36 ms)

Comment: @Nathaniel, if there's a way to preserve formatting (line breaks) when posting that information, let me know. Seems there should be a prettier way to convey that information

Comment: @draca I don't think so in comments, but you can just update the question with that information using the `<pre></pre>` tags as you did for the output of the `free` command.

Comment: In any case, your disk looks fast, so a screenshot of the JetStream2 results will probably be helpful as that will make the "Gmail is slow" problem a bit more quantitative.

Comment: @Nathaniel here is a screenshot of as much as I could fit in one page:  https://imgbox.com/b7gd6F7H

Comment: @draca [Firefox 56](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/56.0/releasenotes/) and later [has a built-in screenshot feature that lets you capture the whole page](http://erinharriswriting.com/capture-screenshot-entire-web-page/), as does Chrome. Also, you can embed the screenshot directly into the question. From what I can see, it looks like your browser is considerably slower than mine. I'll do a write-up as a preliminary sort of answer.

Comment: @draca comments are not meant for such information. You must edit the question and add those. And using outdated software is off-topic on [ubuntu.se] and I think superuser too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information I have about your setup, it sounds like the performance issues are something that's cropped up recently, not something that was happening before. So the point of comparison is with a clean Lubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB, not with Windows 7. This means that roughly speaking, there are three or so possibilities:

1. The slowness is due to a recent change in configuration or software update, perhaps a mismatch between the browser and its dependencies.
2. The slowness is due a hardware issue, such as a failing flash drive or overheating CPU.
3. The slowness is due to an issue outside of your machine, such as a network/router issue or bad Ethernet cable.

Based on the `ioping` results, I don't think it's a failing flash drive, I'd expect more variation in the disk access times. We shouldn't dismiss possibility #3 entirely, but from what I've seen of the [Jetstream](https://browserbench.org/JetStream/) [results](https://imgbox.com/b7gd6F7H), it seems like JavaScript on the browser itself is running slowly, hence why JavaScript-intensive websites like Gmail are running slowly. Therefore, I would more strongly suspect cause #1, a recent change in configuration or a software update. Firefox 78 and Chrome 91 are considerably more recent than the libraries on Lubuntu 14.04, so I'm guessing there is a disharmony between the browsers and their dependencies that is at play.

As others have pointed out, Lubuntu 14.04 was [released in April 2014](https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-1404-trusty-tahr-released/) and had just three years of LTS support, [two years less than plain Ubuntu 14.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes). The [download is no longer available](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04.5/release/), but just for completeness I made an Ubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB and did some benchmarks with Firefox 66.0.3 on my own machine, running on an Intel Core i5-2520M with 16 GB of RAM. It illustrates that your browser is indeed slower at running JavaScript, despite your processor and Firefox version being more recent.

My overall recommendation is to get a new flash drive and install a more recent version of Lubuntu on it. If the performance issues persist, this would point to a hardware or network issue that we have not yet excluded.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ioping .
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=1 time=24 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=2 time=16 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=3 time=15 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=4 time=14 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=5 time=16 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=6 time=17 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=7 time=20 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=8 time=22 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=9 time=17 us
4.0 KiB from . (overlayfs /cow): request=10 time=17 us
^C
--- . (overlayfs /cow) ioping statistics ---
10 requests completed in 9.4 s, 56.2 k iops, 219.5 MiB/s
min/avg/max/mdev = 14 us / 17 us / 24 us / 3 us
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -T ~
Filesystem     Type      1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/cow           overlayfs   8157128 500152   7656976   7% /
```

[image: screenshot of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop with Firefox open]

[image: The about:performance window of Firefox]

[image: Jetstream benchmark results]

Comment: I haven't identified exactly what the cause is yet but I rebooted and after logging in I did not run my initialzation script, I immediately ran the Octane browser benchmark on lubuntu's stock firefox v39 (jetstream wouldnt run on it)  and the score was very fast.  So obviously the cause is somewhere in the installation script that I run after reboot, which does all sorts of things like set up a UFW firewall, apt-get installs things, configures ssh etc.  somewhere in there is the cause.  Thanks for your help and pointing this in the right direction

Comment: @draca You're welcome! Please update your question to add this information along with your other comments so that anyone who reads this later can easily understand what's going on.